# Tell the number of seconds between two given time values

Tags: javascript, html, time

I want to have two `<input type="text">` in my html, one for a starting-point and one for the end-point. you'll then be able to write two times

ex: [8:15] - [14:30] alert("XXXXX seconds")

I want to know how many seconds there are between 8:15 and 14:30. Both times are in the same day. and just to make things simpler (for me at least) i want the result to be alerted.

This will later be used for a progress bar witch will have a start- and end

```
function startTime() {
var today = new Date();
var h = today.getHours();
var m = today.getMinutes();
var s = today.getSeconds();
m = checkTime(m);
s = checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
var s = today.getSeconds();
var sh = document.getElementById('starth').value;
var sm = document.getElementById('startm').value;
var spcode = sh / sm + 1;
var timecode = s + h / m;
if (timecode == spcode) {
    setTimeout(move, 200)
}
}
tion checkTime(i) {
if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
}; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
return i;
}


//Menu
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}

//progress bar

function move() {
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
var nof = document.getElementById('sec').value;
var width = 0;
var id = setInterval(frame, +nof); //1 frame > 4 = 1sec
function frame() {
    if (width >= 999.0) {
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width * 0.1 + '%';
        elem.innerHTML = (width + 1) / 10 + '%';

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Could you at least provide the code to show what have you done by your self?

Comment: Yea, i see understand you, but this is just a tiny link of all the things that are going to work together, so what i have don so far has pretty much nothing to do with this...

Comment: function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
        h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    var sh = document.getElementById('starth').value;
    var sm = document.getElementById('startm').value;
    var spcode = sh / sm + 1;
    var timecode = s + h / m;
    if (timecode == spcode) {
        setTimeout(move, 200)
    }
} [...]

Comment: Then do more and come back when you have specific, code-related problems.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var year = '2018';
var month = '04';
var day = '18';

function diff() {
   var start_time=document.getElementById("start_time").value;
   var end_time=document.getElementById("end_time").value;
   var start_date=new Date(year,month,day,start_time.split(':')[0],start_time.split(':')[1]);
   var end_date=new Date(year,month,day,end_time.split(':')[0],end_time.split(':')[1]);
   var difference=(end_date-start_date)/1000;
   console.log(difference);
   document.getElementById("difference").innerHTML="Differnce is "+difference+" seconds";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="start_time" placeholder="4:15">
<input type="text" id="end_time" placeholder="4:16">
<input type="submit" onclick="diff()">
<p id="difference"></p>
```

Explanation:-

I read two value from input field. Then convert this two value into Date object. Here split will split the string and give array, so it will give me hours and minutes which will be used for converting string to Date. then I substract start_date from end_date which will give me results in milliseacond and by dividing it with 1000 I convert that difference in seconds.

Comment: instead of "console.log(difference)" write "alert(difference)" and it will work